# How to do incremental search in delphi FM2?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Hi i am having a problem with incremental search in delphi.

I Have looked at this http://delphi.about.com/od/vclusing/a/lb_incremental.htm
But this doesn't work in firemonkey so i came up with this :

```
  for I := 0 to lstbxMapList.Items.Count-1 do
  begin
    if lstbxMapList.Items[i] = edtSearch.Text then
    begin
      lstbxMapList.ItemByIndex(i).Visible := True;
    end;

    if lstbxMapList.Items[I] <> edtSearch.Text then
    begin
      lstbxMapList.ItemByIndex(i).Visible := False;
    end;
  end;
```

When i use this the listbox is just blank.

Comment: Ah makes sense now (facepalm). How would i implement incremental then ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're hiding every item that doesn't exactly match `edtSearch.Text`. Try this instead (tested in XE3):

```
// Add StrUtils to your uses clause for `StartsText`
uses
  StrUtils;

procedure TForm1.edtSearchChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  NewIndex: Integer;
begin
  NewIndex := -1;
  for i := 0 to lstBxMapList.Items.Count - 1 do
    if StartsText(Edit1.Text, lstBxMapList.Items[i]) then
    begin
      NewIndex := i;
      Break;
    end;
  // Set to matching index if found, or -1 if not
  lstBxMapList.ItemIndex := NewIndex;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Following from Kens answer, if you want to hide items as per your question, just set the Visible property but note that since the expression of an if statement returns a boolean and Visible is a boolean property it's possible to greatly simplify things. Note also that I've also used ContainsText which will match the string anywhere in the item text:

```
procedure TForm1.edtSearchChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  Item: TListBoxItem;
begin
  for Item in lstbxMapList.ListItems do
    Item.Visible := ContainsText(Item.Text.ToLower, Edit1.Text.ToLower);
end;
```